# URL Fetch and oAuth2 Playground 500 errors

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

Since Thursday last week we have been experiencing bouts of urlfetch errors from Google App Engine. Typically these periods last several hours and causes our application to fail during authorisation. Testing on via the OAuth2 playground sometimes also shows issues.

From the playground when attempting to exchange an authorisation code for a token it reports:

```
Something bad happened: 500 HTTP error. 

Message:  500 Server Error

Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this 
error message and the query that caused it
```

An authorization requests in our code reports:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (3544c942ab0ce9ec) started at 2013/06/11 11:17:17.608 UTC and was still executing at 2013/06/11 11:18:17.027 UTC.
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1033)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:268)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:96)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.get(TimedFuture.java:57)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:69)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:230)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:67)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:201)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:198)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:198)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:67)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:111)
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:38)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:417)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:296)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getResponseCode(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:149)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:95)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:980)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
at com.ourapp.server.OAuthMethods2.handleCallbackIfRequired(OAuthMethods2.java:127)
at com.ourapp.server.OAuthServlet2.handleCallbackIfRequired(OAuthServlet2.java:81)
at com.ourapp.server.AuthLandingServlet.handleCallbackIfRequired(AuthLandingServlet.java:1)
at com.ourapp.server.AuthLandingServlet.doGet(AuthLandingServlet.java:30)
```

or in another form

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:142)
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:43)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:417)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:296)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getResponseCode(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:149)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:95)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:980)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:299)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:323)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:607)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:324)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:526)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:287)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:836)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
at com.ourapp.server.AuthLandingServlet.doGet(AuthLandingServlet.java:34)
```

The exact code that results in the timeout is:

```
GoogleTokenResponse response = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
      transport,
      jsonFactory,
      clientSecrets.getWeb().getClientId(),
      clientSecrets.getWeb().getClientSecret(),
      code,
      clientSecrets.getWeb().getRedirectUris().get(0)).execute();
```

Any ideas what is going on with AppEngine?

Comment: Google has acknowledged this issue on its downtime notify group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/TqKVL9TNq2A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @John Lowry. Google seem to have resolved the app engine problem and authentication is working for us now. I wonder what the underlying issue was.